# want to change the position of React Material-UI DataGrid filter menu popup

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i have implemented React Material-UI DataGrid with filter in toolbar.
[image]

once filter menu/popup open, it'll cover the first few rows of the grid/table, i want this popup to open top-start instead of bottom-start.

is there any way i can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the attributes of this filter element, it's a `div` with a `tooltip` role. As a result, we can create a css file and modify the top position of divs with `tooltip` role as below:

```
div[role="tooltip"] {
  top: -60px !important;
}
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-h1dip?file=/index.css:0-49)

as there isn't any option provided in MUI doc for this issue, I think this would be the best workaround.

Comment: Yes, it's working. thanks for the work around but was looking for a fix via MUI props but it'll work for now

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem today, and, while I know it's been a while, I came here looking for help, and so you might have as well.

You can pass in styles via the component props on the datagrid itself. These styles get applied to the

```
<DataGrid

    // ...omitted for clarity

    componentsProps={{
        panel: {
            sx: {
                top: '-120px !important',
            },
        },
    }}
/>
```

Shout out to [NearHuscarl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9449426/nearhuscarl) who answered [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69549390/add-custom-style-inside-datagrid-toolbars-popup-component-material-ui), and solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to play with `placement` prop in `panel`.

```js
slotProps={
    {
       panel: {anchorEl: elRef, placement: 'bottom'} // by default its bottom-start
    } 
}
```