# Add custom style inside DataGrid Toolbar's popup component Material-UI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

I'm creating a custom `Data Grid Toolbar` component by modifying existing `Grid Toolbar` components from [Material-UI](https://v4.mui.com/).

[Here](https://v4.mui.com/components/data-grid/filtering/) is the official example for the `Grid Toolbar` components:

If we click one of the `Grid Toolbar` components, it will show a popup/popper as seen in the screenshot below.

[image]

What I want to do is to change all font sizes inside every popup/popper from each `Grid Toolbar` component.

I try to change one text for example.
As we can see from the screenshot below, if we inspect the text then change the `font-size` and `color` properties directly, it would change.

[image]

But if I grab and copy the selector (in this case is `.MuiTypography-body1`), then I paste it in my code, there nothing changes (the `font-size` and `color` properties don't change).

Here is the simple code:

```
const CustomGridToolbarColumns = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    color: "dodgerblue",
    "& .MuiTypography-body1": {
      fontSize: 20,
      color: "red"
    }
  }
}))(GridToolbarColumnsButton);
```

I also want to change all `font-size` and `color` properties inside each popup/popper of each `Grid Toolbar` component.
I inspect the popup/popper then change the `font-size` and `color` properties but still don't work as seen in the screenshot below.

[image]

Here are the dependencies (in package.json file):

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
"@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.4",
"@mui/x-data-grid-pro": "^4.0.0",
```

Here is the full code: https://codesandbox.io/s/data-grid-material-ui-custom-toolbar-kd9gj

So **my questions** are:

1. how can we change some properties inside the popup/popper of every `Grid Toolbar` component?
2. how can we change all properties inside the popup/popper of every `Grid Toolbar` component?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can [inspect the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5mnM.png) and see that the component you need to apply the style to is called `GridPanel`. This is the wrapper component of the filters and columns panel. See all the component slots [here](https://v4.mui.com/api/data-grid/data-grid/#slots) for reference.

**V5**

```
<DataGrid
  {...data}
  components={{
    Toolbar: GridToolbar,
  }}
  componentsProps={{
    panel: {
      sx: {
        '& .MuiTypography-root': {
          color: 'dodgerblue',
          fontSize: 20,
        },
        '& .MuiDataGrid-filterForm': {
          bgcolor: 'lightblue',
        },
      },
    },
  }}
/>
```

In order to change the styles of the other 2 `GridMenu`s (density/export), you need to target the `MuiDataGrid-menuList` class name. Currently I see there is no other way around using global styles because `DataGrid` does not allow you to customize the `GridMenu` component:

```
<GlobalStyles
  styles={{
    '.MuiDataGrid-menuList': {
      backgroundColor: 'pink',

      '& .MuiMenuItem-root': {
        fontSize: 26,
      },
    },
  }}
/>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

**V4**

```
import { DataGrid, GridToolbar, GridPanel } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  panel: {
    '& .MuiTypography-root': {
      color: 'dodgerblue',
      fontSize: 20,
    },
  },
});
```

```
<DataGrid
  {...data}
  components={{
    Toolbar: GridToolbar,
  }}
  componentsProps={{
    // GridPanel
    panel: { className: classes.panel },
  }}
/>
```

```
<GlobalStyles
  styles={{
    ".MuiDataGrid-gridMenuList": {
      backgroundColor: "pink",

      "& .MuiMenuItem-root": {
        fontSize: 26
      }
    }
  }}
/>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: great, that works for the `GridToolbarColumnsButton` and `GridToolbarFilterButton` components. I've updated my sandbox using the same way as your answer to style the `GridToolbarDensitySelector` and `GridToolbarExport` components. I inspected the `GridToolbarDensitySelector` and `GridToolbarExport` then I found that the popup from both components had the same parent selector. It was `.MuiGridMenu-root`. But I didn't see any 'Menu' slots from the documentation. So how could I style the popup from `GridToolbarDensitySelector` and `GridToolbarExport` using the same way as yours?

Comment: @JabalLogian This one is a lot harder than I expected, but you can do that by targeting the right className, see my updated answer.

Comment: @NearHuscarl is it possible to do with makeStyles? my react component is already using makeStyles. thanks

Comment: @ZBay I added the `makeStyles` approach in the answer and remove the `withStyles` code since it's not very popular anymore. You can still see both approaches in the codesandbox for reference.